# Iptables not recognizing I'm logged in as root

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, root

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS as a Virtual Machine. When I run `root@:/# sudo iptables -L` I get the following output:

```
iptables v1.6.1: can't initialize iptables table 'filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Running `root@:/# whoami` returns `root` as well.

Running `root@:/# cat /etc/os-release` gives the output:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Running `id root` reports

```
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

When I run `visudo` root has:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

At this point I'm stuck. Any help would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Virtual machine or physical server? (You don't need sudo if you're already root, but that's not the issue.)

Comment: What’s the result of `id root`?  Do you have multiple accounts using the root UID (0)?

Comment: @roaima Virtual machine.

Comment: @bxm `id root` returns `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

Comment: What VM technology are you using?

Comment: Do you have access to the host ? If yes, we need to know which technology you are using (seems to be something like OpenVZ). Otherwise we can only give you instructions what to ask your provider.

Comment: @Maze The VM is hosted via GCP's Compute Engine

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like GCP/CE has a kernel that excludes iptables. There's nothing more anyone here can do for you.

Comment: @roaima That would indeed be a blocker, but could you add a link on where you found that information?

Comment: @AdminBee here you go, I think - [Google Computer Engine Firewall and IpTables](https://serverfault.com/a/666527/267016)

Comment: @roaima That link doesn't say that the kernel excludes iptables, I don't think. The accepted answers itself says "For an instance to see an incoming connection both firewalls must allow it." which implies that iptables is something that can be worked with.